# DoDragDrop plus BeginInvoke plus MessageBox hangs program

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox, freeze, begininvoke

Placing the `MessageBox.Show(...)` inside a `BeginInvoke` results in the application freezing.

It seems like the `DoDragDrop` is part of the problem. If a tab is clicked without dragging, then it won't freeze.

Everything is being executed on the UI thread, so I think the code is written as it should be.

**Is there something wrong in the code or is this a bug in .NET?**

I've tested on .NET 3.5 4.0 and 4.5, same result on each.

Here is a minimal stripped down that exhibits the behavior.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DynamicTests {

public class Form2 : Form {

    public Form2() {
        TabControl2 tc = new TabControl2 { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            TabPage tp = new TabPage("Tab Page " + i);
            tc.TabPages.Add(tp);
        }

        tc.SelectedIndexChanged += tc_SelectedIndexChanged;
        this.Controls.Add(tc);
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Size = new Size(600, 600);
    }

    void tc_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        // click and drag a tab + BeginInvoke results in the message
        // freezing the application 
        this.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Congrats, the program is locked.");

            // one possible solution is to show the message on a thread
            // but the form cannot be used as the parent window
            //Thread t = new Thread(() => {
            //  MessageBox.Show("Congrats, the program is locked.");
            //});
            //t.Start();
        });
    }

}

public class TabControl2 : TabControl {

    private TabPage dragTab2 = null; // tab currently being dragged

    public TabControl2() : base() {
        this.AllowDrop = true; // required for dragging tabs
    }

    private int HotTabIndex { get; set; }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        dragTab2 = null;
        if (HotTabIndex >= 0) {
            dragTab2 = this.TabPages[HotTabIndex];
        }
    }

    bool cancelSelecting = false;

    // For tabs with a [x] close button, if the user clicks the close button, it doesn't make sense to first show the tab and then close it.
    // Also, some tabs are lazy loaded.  The Control the TabPage is hosting is not initialized until the tab is selected.  So it's a short
    // but noticeable time that the control is created (and it may query a database taking more time)... only to be closed.
    //
    // The solution is to intercept the left mouse button and set cancelSelecting to true.  Then in the OnSelecting(...) method, what would
    // normally happen is the tab appears right away.  However, because the user might have clicked the close button, the selection of the
    // tab was moved to the OnMouseUp(...) method.
    //
    // This behavior is similar to windows.  If you click the [X] on a window, and hold the mouse, the window does not close.
    // Thus, you can move the mouse off the button if you change your mind.
    protected override void DefWndProc(ref Message m) {
        const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
        if (m.Msg == (int) WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {
            cancelSelecting = true;
        }

        base.DefWndProc(ref m);
    }

    protected override void OnSelecting(TabControlCancelEventArgs e) {
        base.OnSelecting(e);
        e.Cancel = cancelSelecting;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        HotTabIndex = -1;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
        cancelSelecting = false; // must set to false here so that drag tab works correctly
        base.OnMouseMove(e);

        //// TCM_HITTEST checks to see if the mouse is over a new tab
        TCHITTESTINFO HTI = new TCHITTESTINFO(e.X, e.Y);
        HotTabIndex = SendMessage(this.Handle, TCM_HITTEST, IntPtr.Zero, ref HTI);

        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left || dragTab2 == null) // not dragging
            return;

         // we have to do this because we don't select on click
         // if this isn't done then sometimes a sloppy click (click with small drag) wouldn't select the tab
        this.SelectedTab = dragTab2;
        this.DoDragDrop(dragTab2, DragDropEffects.All); // start drag
    }

    protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e) {
        base.OnDragOver(e);

        TabControl tc = this;

        // a tab is dragged?
        if (e.Data.GetData(typeof(TabPage)) == null)
            return;

        TabPage dragTab = (TabPage) e.Data.GetData(typeof(TabPage));
        TabControl tc2 = dragTab.Parent as TabControl;
        if (tc2 == null)
            return;

        int dragTab_index = tc.TabPages.IndexOf(dragTab);

        // hover over a tab?
        int hoverTab_index = getHoverTabIndex(tc);
        if (hoverTab_index < 0) {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
            return;
        }
        TabPage hoverTab = tc.TabPages[hoverTab_index];
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;

        if (dragTab == hoverTab)
            return;

        // swap dragTab & hoverTab - avoids toggeling
        Rectangle dragTabRect = tc.GetTabRect(dragTab_index);
        Rectangle hoverTabRect = tc.GetTabRect(hoverTab_index);

        if (dragTabRect.Width < hoverTabRect.Width) {
            Point tcLocation = tc.PointToScreen(tc.Location);

            if (dragTab_index < hoverTab_index) {
                if ((e.X - tcLocation.X) > ((hoverTabRect.X + hoverTabRect.Width) - dragTabRect.Width))
                    swapTabPages(tc, dragTab, hoverTab);
            } else if (dragTab_index > hoverTab_index) {
                if ((e.X - tcLocation.X) < (hoverTabRect.X + dragTabRect.Width))
                    swapTabPages(tc, dragTab, hoverTab);
            }
        }
        else
            swapTabPages(tc, dragTab, hoverTab);

        // select new pos of dragTab
        tc.SelectedIndex = tc.TabPages.IndexOf(dragTab);
    }

    private static int getHoverTabIndex(TabControl tc) {
        Point xy = tc.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        for (int i = 0; i < tc.TabPages.Count; i++) {
            if (tc.GetTabRect(i).Contains(xy))
                return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    private static void swapTabPages(TabControl tc, TabPage src, TabPage dst) {
        int index_src = tc.TabPages.IndexOf(src);
        int index_dst = tc.TabPages.IndexOf(dst);
        tc.TabPages[index_dst] = src;
        tc.TabPages[index_src] = dst;
        tc.Refresh();
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, ref TCHITTESTINFO lParam);

    [StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct TCHITTESTINFO {
        public Point pt;
        public TCHITTESTFLAGS flags;
        public TCHITTESTINFO(int x, int y) {
            pt = new Point(x, y);
            flags = TCHITTESTFLAGS.TCHT_NOWHERE;
        }
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum TCHITTESTFLAGS {
        TCHT_NOWHERE = 1,
        TCHT_ONITEMICON = 2,
        TCHT_ONITEMLABEL = 4,
        TCHT_ONITEM = TCHT_ONITEMICON | TCHT_ONITEMLABEL
    }

    private const int TCM_FIRST = 0x1300;
    private const int TCM_HITTEST = TCM_FIRST + 13;

}


}

/*
    Call Stack when hang:

    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.ShowCore(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window owner, string text, string caption, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons buttons, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon icon, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxOptions options, bool showHelp) + 0x44a bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window owner, string text) + 0x3a bytes    
>   DynamicTests.exe!DynamicTests.Form2.tc_SelectedIndexChanged.AnonymousMethod__1() Line 28 + 0x16 bytes   C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(object[] args) + 0x6a bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ThreadMethodEntry tme) + 0x97 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(object obj) + 0xef bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x285 bytes 
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x9 bytes   
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x57 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ThreadMethodEntry tme) + 0x113 bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks() + 0x10c bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x2b8 bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x1ee bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x145 bytes    
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.DoDragDrop(object data, System.Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects allowedEffects) + 0x187 bytes    
    DynamicTests.exe!DynamicTests.TabControl2.OnMouseMove(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) Line 97 + 0x20 bytes   C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseMove(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x89 bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0xe64 bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x416 bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x145 bytes    
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData) + 0x681 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x56f bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x6f bytes    
    DynamicTests.exe!DynamicTests.Program.Main() Line 149 + 0x2a bytes  C#
*/
```

Comment: Well, sure, DoDragDrop() starts a modal loop that swallows all the mouse messages.  Since they are needed to trigger the D+D events.  Showing a dialog while that modal loop is active is going to be ... interesting.  I suppose you could press the space bar to click the OK button :)  If it hurts then don't do it.

Comment: @HansPassant On my machine, the entire UI thread locks up, so it's not possible to dismiss the message box by space bar or OK button. Different on your machine?

Comment: Yes, space still works.  Win81.  Hard to see why that matters, this is not usable as-is anyway.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for confirming. I'm also running Win8.1. I'll try updating and see if the deadlock goes away. In the real code, the application displays which tabs the user previously had open, but lazy loads the tab's UI when clicked so that the application loads faster. The message box is only displayed if an error happened instantiating the user control.